# Is it possible to dynamically set the "require" option on a AngularJs Directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am attempting to understand if it is possible to dynamically set the "require" option of a directive.  For example...

```
  app.directive('test', [function () {
  return {
    require: someVar
  }}
```

I would like to access an unknown controller inside "test".  The controller is unknown because I am generating pages dynamically through configuration. Idealistically I would like to...

```
<test some-var="^parent"><test>
```

Edit - I should also state that I only want to set it once on page load.  It would not change after that.

Thanks,

Chad

Comment: Do you really need to `require` it then? Couldn't you simply use scope inheritance or pass what you need by bindings?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `require` is like using an API - you need to know what the controller that you will get expose as its public API for this to make sense. So, to avoid an XY question, give an example of what you are trying to achieve at the end

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access the controller of a directive, or to access an arbitrary controller? As per your question, it sounds like you just want a controller, which would require using a different approach than the require method.

```
directive('testDirective',function() {

  var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: link,
    name: "myController",
    controller: "@",
    controllerAs: "vm",
    bindToController: true,
    template: "<div>{{vm.testMessage}}</div>"
  }

  return directive;

  function link(scope,iElement,iAttrs) {

  }

});
```

In this case, the controller that's bound to the template is driven by the name property, which can be assigned on the directive DOM element, like so

```
<test-directive my-controller="mainController"></test-directive>
```

with the my-controller property set to mainController, you could have an arbitrary controller defined that defines the testMessage property on itself

```
controller('sampleOneController', function() {
   var vm = this;
   vm.testMessage = "from sample One Controller"; 
}).
```

here's a jsfiddle with this demonstrated

https://jsfiddle.net/0302gLav/32/